# Evaluate $\int \frac{1}{(x^2+a^2)^\frac{3}{2}}dx$

Tags: integration

I used substitutions $x=at,dx=adt$ and $x^2+a^2=t^2$ but that didn't work. Could someone tell how to solve this integral?

Comment: have you tried a trig substituion, eg $x=a\tan\theta$?

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, use 
$$
I(a)=\frac{1}{2a}\partial_a\int dx \frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+x^2}}
$$

The last integral is elementary and yields $\text{arcsinh}(x/a)$. I'm sure you can take it from here!

Answer (score 1):

Try using $x=a \tan \theta$. It works out very nicely from there =)

Answer (score 0):

The substitution $x=a\sinh{(y)}$ also works fine: maybe not as fast as $x=a\tan{(\theta)}$, but it is worth knowing.